# email protector: Is this code still secure today?

Tags: php, javascript

I found this nice email protector script from css-tricks.com [(link)](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/email-protector/)

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    function php_split_js_make_email($phpemail)
    {
        $pieces = explode("@", $phpemail);

        echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var a = "<a href=\'mailto:";
                var b = "' . $pieces[0] . '";
                var c = "' . $pieces[1] .'";
                var d = "\' class=\'email\'>";
                var e = "</a>";
                document.write(a+b+"@"+c+d+b+"@"+c+e);
            </script>
            <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view emails</noscript>
        ';
    }
?>
```

Usage

```
<?php php_split_js_make_email("youremail@here.com"); ?>
```

Now I would like to know how secure this code is today, since this post is more than a year old now...

Thank you

Comment: That code was never "secure". Spammers will generally win the arms race for finding e-mails on websites. Luckily, spam filters are generally winning the arms race on not displaying them in your inbox.

Comment: This probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you really need to protect mail addresses, check [recaptcha](http://www.recaptcha.com)

Comment: You might want to check [Mailhid (reCaptcha)](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/mailhide/)

Comment: Any email harvester can run JavaScript. It is so simple to script, only a few lines of code.

Comment: @DanielM - I wish I could -1 your comment. [What the web needs is *less* captchas, not more](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/07/02/why-you-should-never-use-a-captcha/). I spent 10 minutes yesterday battling TicketMaster trying to decipher their impossible captchas. Ugh.

Comment: thanks all, appreciate the feedback. So basically, what you're all telling me, is I might as well to the normal html mailto: attribute?

Comment: @j08691: Secure I mean from protecting my email address form spambots harvesting my email address...

Comment: @gilly3: Well then, thank god you cant. As long as there is no solution to this issue, captchas are a way to solve this. Btw, this is about an email address. Not every visitor of a website wants to read it, only those who want to contact the guy behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is only secure if the robot sniffing your page for email addresses doesn't execute the JavaScript.

On [my personal site](http://jumpingfishes.com), I embed my email address as an image and use an online form to send mail instead of a mailto link.

Comment: well, you said -1 to another answer for suggesting Captch. Presumably because spammers are able to defeat it easily using OCR. And then you say you embed your email address as an image??? Surely that's just as easy (or easier) to defeat than a captcha?

Comment: Isn't a picture of an email effectively a captcha? Apart from that: How do you protect against bot sending you massive amounts of spam using the form?

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful...What do you use for the online form to send emails? Swift Mailer...etc or custom own code?

Comment: also, your image, is it just a normal image without captcha-like characters? Can't bots decipher the letters inside the image?

Comment: If they can decipher complicated captchas better then some of us humans, I would guess they can read those captchas.

Comment: ok...what about your images...is it a normal font-orientated image? would that suffice?

Comment: @SDC - I would be highly surprised to find a bot that is running OCR on every image it finds when it crawls a site to look for email addresses within that image. Defeating a captcha with OCR is more feasible because they are able to target just captchas, not every image they encounter.

Comment: @gilly3 - Fair point! But at least in your case it seems you expose the fact that the image contains text. Maybe you should change the URL ("TextToImage.ashx?id=1&h=16&w=152") to be less ... obvious?

Comment: @MarcusRiemer - The email picture is not obscured in any way and is provided for openness only.  I provide the contact form as a simple way to send me email.  I've not received one piece of spam yet.  I'll solve that problem when it becomes a problem.

Comment: @DextrousDave - I wrote a custom handler in C# to send mail. Yes, the image is intended to appear as plain text.  I'm not worried about email harvesters trying to use OCR to detect email addresses embedded in images.  That seems unlikely.  To see the email image, [go to my website and take a look](http://jumpingfishes.com).

Comment: @MarcusRiemer - Great point about the obvious url. That's probably something I should change *before* a spam bot finds my email address.

Comment: @gilly3 Additional thought: Even though the picture is not obscured, it *does* lock out e.g. blind people with screen readers. I usually vote for simple "non image" captchas using questions that are trivialy solvable for visitors of my pages. (Of course, the inventors of re-captcha might argue their captchas are "trivialy solvable" aswell ... So take this with a grain of salt ...)

Comment: @MarcusRiemer - Ya, blind folks won't be able to see my email address, but it shouldn't prevent them from contacting me. My contact form is keyboard accessible. I haven't actually done any real accessibility testing though, so I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to protect against bots harvesting email adresses? Then probably not. More and more scrapers are able to execute javascript code, tools like [phantomjs](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) make it easy to scrape contents of javascript sites.

In general you should try not to expose such data publicly. How many of the people visiting your page are interested in the address?

Consider to add some kind of authentication check like a captcha or login process for those people. Or to put it the other way round: Dont show **everyone** sensitive data you don't want to have scraped. And keep in mind that there is no 100% protection against scrapers. Oh, and when using captchas please use something sensible! I would **bet** most bots can solve that re-captcha service better then me ... In many cases you are fine with a very basic set of "common sense" questions.

Comment: That was meant to be an example, not a silver bullet. But it guess we won't agree on that ;)

Comment: I prefer [this alternative to captcha](http://xkcd.com/810/).  Or maybe [this one](http://xkcd.com/233/).

Comment: Captchas aren't necesarily about images ;) They are a "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart" and may use whatever solves that problem best.